# gevent and pymongo ajax problems

Tags: mongodb, heroku, pymongo, bottle, gevent

I have a singlepage web app on bottle.py with gevent as a server (hosted in Heroku).

Page sends ajax request, server gets data from MongoDB (map-reduce) and returns json.
In one time maybe sends several requests to one handler with different params.

Problem:

In development mode (non-threading default bottle server) ajax returns always correct data.
With gevent server returned data is everytyme different.

monkey.patch_all() is used,

pymongo connection in one global variable

bottle.py 0.11.7

pymongo 2.9.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try Lock you function:

```
from threading import Lock

lock = Lock()

@get('/something/')
def something():
    with lock:
        # your code
    return your_result
```